# Why doesn't GHC give a compile time warning for the "No match in record selector" exception?

Tags: haskell, ghc

When I run this buggy code...

```
data Person = Adult { pName :: String}
            | Kid   { pName :: String
                    , pAge  :: Int
                    } deriving Show

getAge :: Person -> Int
getAge p = pAge p

getName :: Person -> String
getName p = pName p

main :: IO ()
main = do

  let p1 = Kid "fred" 5
      p2 = Adult "john"
      ps = [p1, p2]

  names = map getName ps
  ages = map getAge ps

  putStrLn $ "names: " ++ show names
  putStrLn $ "ages: " ++ show ages
```

... I get this in ghci:

```
names: ["fred","john"]

ages: [5,* * * Exception: No match in record selector pAge
```

I know how to avoid this error, but I'm wondering why compiling with "ghc -Wall" didn't warn me about this problem.  Is there another tool that can help me to prevent this type of error?

Comment: I bet the GHC folks would be willing to stick a warning in for this. You should file a feature request on [Trac](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/newticket?type=feature+request)!

Comment: There is a general sentiment of dissatisfaction around records in their current form. Some folks are investigating alternatives. In the meantime, multiple-constructors records are not recommanded, and should be a warning of their own :-)

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7169 - you might add yourself to cc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there [a] tool that can help me to prevent this type of error?

No, but there could be.

As you know, record syntax automatically generates getters with the same name as the attributes you define. Therefore the code

```
data Person = Adult { pName :: String}
            | Kid   { pName :: String
                    , pAge  :: Int
                    } deriving Show
```

creates the functions `pName :: Person -> String` and `pAge :: Person -> Int`. Now, *suppose* Haskell had subtyping. If it did, then `Kid` could be a subtype of `Person`, and `pAge` could have the more appropriate type `Kid -> String`. However, Haskell does *not* have subtyping, and there is therefore no `Kid` type.

Now, given that `Person -> String` is the most specific type we can give to `pAge`, why not warn that `pAge` is a partial function at compile time? Let me divert the question by referring to the List example

```
data List a = Cons { head :: a, tail :: List a } | Empty
```

In this example, `head` and `tail` are partial functions: the two components of a non-empty list, but (due to Haskell's lack of subtyping) meaningless accessors on the empty list. So, why no warning by default? Well, by default, you know the code you have written. The compiler doesn't provide warnings if you use `unsafePerformIO`, because you're the programmer here, you're expected to use such things responsibly.

So **tl;dr**: if you want the warning here:

```
getAge :: Person -> Int
getAge p = pAge p
```

then you're out of luck, because the type system does not have enough information to deduce that this is a problem.

If you want the warning here:

```
data Person = Adult | Kid { pAge :: Int }
```

then I'm sure it would be trivial to implement: just check that a given field exists in some constructors but not others. But I do not foresee this warning being widely useful for everyone; some might complain that it would be just noise.

Comment: The compiler could notice, however, that *pAge* is a partial function, and could warn users of that function. Yet, there are cases where totalness of functions cannot be recognized, hence one would also get warnings there.

Comment: Subtyping is not strictly necessary here. @Tad can have a `Adult` and a `Kid` type if he wants to. If he wants a common interface for accessing ages, he can use a typeclass, or a `Person` type.

Comment: Dan said:  So, why no warning by default? Well, by default, you know the code you have written. The compiler doesn't provide warnings if you use unsafePerformIO, because you're the programmer here, you're expected to use such things responsibly. --

Comment: Dan said:  So, why no warning by default? Well, by default, you know the code you have written. The compiler doesn't provide warnings if you use unsafePerformIO, because you're the programmer here, you're expected to use such things responsibly. -- That is true.  But -Wall warns me about shadowed variable and other warnings that I like to turn off with -f-no-warn...  In this particular case, as this is the first time I made this error, I thought a warning would be helpful. In my mind, that's preferable to a run-time exception. As Daniel Wagner suggested, I may file a Trac feature request.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be surprised if http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/catch/ doesn't pick this up.

Answer (score 2):

It does, since 8.4, with `-Wpartial-fields`.

https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html#ghc-flag--Wpartial-fields

Comment: doh - "The warning is suppressed if the field name begins with an underscore."